# Can I use a different root element in a HTML page?

Tags: html, html-parsing, doctype

Out of curiosity I was reading the [Document Type Declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration) article on Wikipedia when I discovered the role of `HTML` in the DOCTYPE declaration:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

According to Wikipedia, the first attribute `HTML` is the root element of the document, and thus should be opened first.

> ...in XHTML, the root element is `<html>`, being the first element opened (after the doctype declaration) and last closed.

So I was wondering, if I were to structure a document as so:

```
<!DOCTYPE burrito PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<burrito>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    A burrito is a great way to wrap a webpage.
    </body>
</burrito>
```

would a web browser consume my `<burrito>` or wrap it in a `<html>` tag?

Comment: It will be wrapped with `<html>`.

Comment: You can read something useful [here](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_browser_main_functionality);

Comment: "consume my `<burrito>`"... pun intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is “No”, because all HTML specifications define the `html` element as the root element. The question what error processing browsers might apply and why when you violate this isn’t particularly interesting, and differences between browsers are to be expected.

In any case, the phoney `doctype` makes browsers go to Quirks Mode, and it serves no purpose, as browsers do not care about the `doctype`, except as regards to Quirks Mode, “Standards Mode”, or some intermediate mode. They do not even read the document type definition referred to, so they won’t detect the mismatch.

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question as to why it wraps it.

Answer (score 1):

It will be wrapped in `<html>`. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE burrito PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>....</head>
    <body>
        <burrito>
            A burrito is a great way to wrap a webpage.
        </burrito>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suppose the question I should have posed was why?

Comment: @liamzebedee: Because you're talking about an HTML page?

Comment: If you ask "why"? I'm not sure, but "maybe" it's the standard format for all the browsers. And they are set to render html pages that way?